# unmasking a oval like a clock

Tags: actionscript-3

i have an circle shape, and what i would like to achieve is that it gets masked and thenon enter frame it zhould get unmasked like a clock, so you get to see from 0 to 1, then from 0 to 2, 0 to 3, etc, i know it has to be done with radiants etc but math isnt really my cup of tea. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a mask Sprite for your shape

Step 2: Calculate the angle you need:

```
var endAngle:Number = 360 / 12 * clockTime;
```

where clockTime is your hours. For minutes, use 360/60.

Step 3: Refresh the mask on ENTER_FRAME

You have to draw a pie slice using curveTo.  Use `maskSprite.graphics.clear()` and `maskSprite.graphics.beginFill(0,1)`, then call:

```
function drawClockSlice (sprite : Sprite, centerX : Number, centerY : Number, endAngle : Number, radius : Number) : void
{
    var g : Graphics = sprite.graphics;
    var controlPoint : Point;
    var anchorPoint : Point;

    var startRadians:Number = Math.PI / 180 * -90;
    var endRadians : Number = Math.PI / 180 * (endAngle-90);

    var difference : Number = Math.abs( endRadians - startRadians );
    var divisions : Number = Math.floor( difference / (Math.PI / 4) ) + 1;
    var span : Number = difference / (2 * divisions);
    var controlRadius : Number = radius / Math.cos( span );

    g.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    g.lineTo(centerX + (Math.cos( startRadians ) * radius), centerY + Math.sin( startRadians ) * radius );

    for (var i : Number = 0; i < divisions; ++i)
    {
        endRadians = startRadians + span;
        startRadians = endRadians + span;
        controlPoint = new Point( centerX + Math.cos( endRadians ) * controlRadius, centerY + Math.sin( endRadians ) * controlRadius );
        anchorPoint = new Point( centerX + Math.cos( startRadians ) * radius, centerY + Math.sin( startRadians ) * radius );
        g.curveTo( controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y, anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y );
    }
    g.lineTo( centerX, centerY );
}
```

(I've taken and edited the above code from a related [example by meddlingwithfir](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=192099))

Don't forget your `endFill()`!